# MySQL query: UPDATE on duplicate key, append data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data as this.

```
A       B
----------
dataA   1
dataB   2
dataC   3

----------
```

I can do

```
"UPDATE table SET A = `dataNew` WHERE A = `dataC`;"
```

but I have problem when doing some update like this

```
"UPDATE table SET A = 'dataA' WHERE A = 'dataC';"
```

how can I append so that if the data exists, it will become

```
"UPDATE table SET A = 'dataA_1' WHERE A = 'dataC';"
```

I try

```
UPDATE table SET A = 'dataA' WHERE A = 'dataC' ON DULPLICATE KEY UPDATE A = CONCAT('dataA', '_1');
```

but it is not valid. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to check if the new value exists.  This is a bit tricky.  You cannot use a `join` or `cross join`, because if the column does not exist, no rows will be returned.  So, this uses a `left join`:

```
UPDATE table t left join
       (select t.*
        from table t
        where A = 'dataA'
       ) tA
       on 1=1
    SET t.A = (case when tA.A is not null then 'dataA_1' else 'dataA' end)
    WHERE t.A = 'dataC';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gordon, I've built this query. Can't be sure how expensive this is, but it works.

```
UPDATE myTable t1 
   LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A = 'ABC') t2 ON 1=1
      LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT MAX(A) AS A FROM myTable 
            WHERE A REGEXP 'ABC_[0-9]*$') t3 ON 1=1
SET t1.A = 
   (CASE WHEN t2.A IS NULL THEN 'ABC' ELSE
      (CASE WHEN t3.A IS NULL THEN CONCAT('ABC_',1)
         ELSE CONCAT('ABC_',SUBSTRING(t3.A,5,100) + 1) END )
   END)
WHERE t1.A = 'GHI'
```

The schema that I use.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (`A` varchar(20), `B` int, `C` varchar(10)) ;

ALTER TABLE myTable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (A);

INSERT INTO myTable (`A`, `B`, `C`) VALUES
   ('ABC', 1, 'ABC'),
   ('ABC_1', 1, 'ABC'),
   ('ABC_2', 1, 'ABC'),
   ('ABC_245', 1, 'ABC'),
   ('ABC_1asdasd', 1, 'ABC'),
   ('DEF', 2, 'DEF'),
   ('GHI', 3, 'GHI');
```

Please comment if this is actually bad;

Comment: /* php */  
    $newdata = "ABC_";  
    $length = count($newdata) + 1;  

    $sql += "(CASE WHEN t3.A IS NULL THEN CONCAT('". **$newdata** ."',1)  
         ELSE CONCAT('". **$newdata** ."',SUBSTRING(t3.A,". **$length** .",100) + 1) END )